# HttpClient 4.3 set source port

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient 4.3. I would like to set source port (or local port) for each request. I didn't see any method on HttpClient or HttpGet class. On the Server side, we have written security code (kind of whitelist IP with port number) to check incoming request ip and port number (this is all within intranet with static ips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setLocalAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1}))
        .build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("/");
httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
```

**Correction:**

Explicit setting of local ports is not supported by HttpClien 4.x

Comment: I would like to set the local port.

Comment: I understand black- / white-listing based on ip address. But based on port?

Comment: Ok. As explicit setting of local port is not supported, We need to rethink our security stuff on server. Thank you for your quick answer.